# PHP: json_encode changing slash to \/

Tags: php

I have a variable which contains a path in json_encode 
 /users/crazy_bash/online/test/

but json_encode converts the path to this:

```
 \/users\/crazy_bash\/online\/test\/
```

Why? How can i display a normal path?

the code

```
$pl2 = json_encode(array(
    'comment' => $nmp3,
    'file' => $pmp3
));
echo($pl2);
```

Comment: Well, that's what `json_encode()` is supposed to do, no? If you decode the json string, it'll be correct again, won't it?

Comment: tried using json_decode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's perfectly legal JSON, see http://json.org/. `\/` is converted to `/` when unserializing the string. Why worry about it if the output is unserialized by a proper JSON parser?

If you insist on having `\/` in your output, you can use `str_replace()`:

```
// $data contains: {"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/"}
$data = str_replace("\\/", "/", $data);
echo $data; // {"url":"http://example.com/"}
```

Note that it's still valid JSON by the definition of a string:

[image: JSON string]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>

Comment: Isn't the picture showing that both forward and back slashes need to escaped to be valid JSON?

Comment: Sure it is ... and what's the problem?

Comment: @Rocket no, it says that `Any UNICODE character except " or \ or control character` are allowed (which includes forward and backslashes). In addition, `\/` is recognized as well and it will become `/`. There are multiple ways to specify a forward slash, including `\u002F`

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Ah, ok, the chart was a bit confusing :-P

Answer (score 6):

Escaped solidus is legal. But if you want a result without escaping, use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`in json_encode option. However, this was added after PHP 5.4.
So, `str_replace('\\/', '/', $pl2);` would be helpful.

Comment: There's no reason to do this, once parsed or decoded, the string is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But a solidus without escaping is also legal. And 'cleaner(very subjective)' or 'humanized' result will be helpful for someone. I agree with this post; http://noteslog.com/post/the-solidus-issue/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decode it before usage.

`json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

That's what `json_encode` is supposed to do.  Once you `json_decode` or `JSON.parse` it, it's fine.

```
var f = {"a":"\/users\/crazy_bash\/online\/test\/"}
console.log(f.a); // "/users/crazy_bash/online/test/"

var h = JSON.parse('{"a":"\/users\/crazy_bash\/online\/test\/"}');
console.log(h.a); // "/users/crazy_bash/online/test/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, basically you need to decode your data and then do the encode, so it works correctly without bars, check the code.

```php
$getData = json_decode($getTable);                  
$json = json_encode($getData);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print $json;
```